# PyQt5 How can I update cell value Qtablewidget in iteration loop using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qt5

I want to update cell of row one by one.Just like in Ajax, table value updating one by one row.Currently I am using iteration loop for updating table one by one row.but it does not updating row one by one also freeze GUI when background process is running.
Is there any other way for achieving one by one row updation.
Creating table I have used QtableWidget.

```
        with open('test.csv') as f:
            reader = csv.DictReader(f)
            for i,row in enumerate(reader):
                print("i",i)
                print(row)
                marks= row['Marks']
                total= self.total(marks)
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(total)))
                time.sleep(1)
```

Issue with getting freeze GUI and not updating row one by one.
I want to update it one by one.
Please give me suggestion, Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try adding `QApplication.processEvents()` to the end of the for-loop.

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro It's working as I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No blocking should *ever* happen within a UI program (at least, not in its *main thread*): GUI frameworks use an event loop which constantly processes incoming events from the system (including user interaction) and allows correct rendering updates.

The UI can correctly update itself only when a function returns control to the event loop, and in your case that won't happen until the function ends, which could take a while due to the `time.sleep`.

In order to perform "delayed" and repeated tasks, you can use a `QTimer`.

```
    def fillTable(self):
        with open('test.csv') as f:
            self.csvIterator = csv.DictReader(f)

        self.fillRow = 0
        self.fillTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.fillTimer.setInterval(1000)
        self.fillTimer.timeout.connect(self.updateTable)
        self.fillTimer.start()

    def updateTable(self):
        try:
            row = next(self.csvIterator)
        except StopIteration:
            self.fillTimer.stop()
            return
        print('i', self.fillRow)
        print(row)
        marks = row['Marks']
        total = self.total(marks)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(self.fillRow, 4, QTableWidgetItem(str(total)))
        self.fillRow += 1
```